# What does 'equal' mean for morphisms of a category?

Tags: category-theory

I don't quite understand what does equal mean for morphisms in category theory. Since object of a category is not necessarily a collection of some elements, then how to decide whether two morphisms are the same or not? Is it allowed that for some category $C$, there exist two different morphisms $f,g$, but for any possible  h which is not a identity morphism, $f\circ h = g\circ h$ and $h\circ f = h\circ g$ (so that there does not exist any monic or epi morphisms in this category, and any objects $a$ of this category do not have any structure such as $x \in a$)? Or we can never know it?

Comment: $Mor(A,B)$ is a set, so you can speak of equality of members of this set.

Comment: @Randall It's not necessarily a set. If it is a set in your category, then what you have is a locally small category. Not all categories are locally small.

Comment: To me, all categories are locally small.

Comment: There cannot exist two different morphisms $f, g$ such that for any possible $h$, $f \circ h = g \circ h$. Indeed, pick as $h$ the identity morphism, and you get that $f = g$.

Comment: @LucaBressan Thx for pointing out it. I think indentity morphism should be exculded, and thus there is no invertible morphisms.

Comment: @Randall, that's not a universal convention (as evidenced by the fact that the property has a separate name), so you really ought to state that assumption explicitly. It's true that any concrete category I have ever worked with myself has been locally small, but it's not part of how I define a category.

Comment: @Arthur  I completely understand that times have changed, but for those of us who grew up on Hilton-Stammbach and MacLane---where hom-sets are truly sets---it's an unbreakable habit.

Comment: This being said, whether it's a set or a proper class does not change the fact that equality of members (and thus morphisms) is hardcoded in the structure.